# how to fix UI chat tableview after send image

Tags: swift, error-handling, tableview, chat, project

I was making a chat app, After sending the image once, the data load on the chat `tableview` is weird. I wrote 'hello' as shown in the picture, but there is an error such as adding an image.

There is no problem if you just send text, but after sending the image, the error keeps getting that UI error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some code so we can better identify what's happening?

Comment: I think this problem is caused by cell reuse. But I don't know the solution.